swig: Failed to Download Resource "swig" Due to Connection Timeout
I am encountering an issue while trying to download and install Watchman using the Homebrew command brew install watchman. The process fails during the download with the following error message:
==> Fetching swig
==> Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/0f6a079
######################################################################### 100.0%
==> Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/swig/swig/swig-4.3.0/s
######################################################################### 100.0%  
curl: (28) Failed to connect to cyfuture.dl.sourceforge.net port 443 after 75084 ms: 
Couldn't connect to server
Warning: Problem : timeout. Will retry in 1 seconds. 3 retries left.
######################################################################### 100.0%
Failed to connect to 
cyfuture.dl.sourceforge.net port 443 after 75003 ms: Couldn't connect to server
Warning: Problem : timeout. Will retry in 2 seconds. 2 retries left.
######################################################################### 100.0%  - 
Failed to connect to 
cyfuture.dl.sourceforge.net port 443 after 75002 ms: Couldn't connect to server
Warning: Problem : timeout. Will retry in 4 seconds. 1 retries left.
######################################################################### 100.0%                                   
curl: (28) Failed to connect to cyfuture.dl.sourceforge.net port 443 after 75064 ms: 
Couldn't connect to server

The issue seems to be a connection timeout when attempting to download the resource from the SourceForge server.
Solutions I’ve Tried:

Disabled the firewall.
Disabled the proxy.
Tested the connection with and without VPN.
Uninstalled and reinstalled SWIG and Homebrew.
Restarted the system.

Additionally, I tried the following commands:

brew cleanup -s

brew install --force watchman

watchman shutdown-server

brew update

brew reinstall watchman

rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core; brew update


Despite these efforts, the issue persists.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve it?
